# MacVim.app doesnt open any edit windows

Tags: macos, homebrew, macvim

i installed macvim with

```
brew install macvim
brew link macvim
brew linkapps
```

i am on os x el capitan, but had same problem on yosemite

if i go to /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-80/bin and execute macvim script from there, it works fine and opens a new window

command-line vim works fine.

but if i launch MacVim from Applications, it doesnt do anything. i can access macvim preferences/file menu, i can call open file dialog, but edit window doesnt open when i choose a file!

ok, there is open issue about this: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/109

Comment: Try this: `defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMLoginShell -bool NO`. Does it work?

Answer (score 3):

If your `.bash_profile` has any shell command that spawns a new shell, it probably is the culprit. Try run:

`defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMLoginShell -bool NO`

If it works, you can look at the technical details [here](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/109).